# The request for an image remains suspended with spring webflux functional

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux, project-reactor

i need to give back an image stored in mogodb with gridfs but every time I get the image, the request remains suspended. In particular, this happens with images over 40k.
Actually i use spring data mongodb reactive 2.2.0.M2.

The code used is the following

MediaRepository.kt

```
fun getById(id: String): Mono<ReactiveGridFsResource> {
    return gridFsOperations.findFirst(Query(Criteria.where("_id").`is`(id)))
        .flatMap { file ->
            gridFsOperations.getResource(file)
        }
}
```

MediaHandler.kt

```
fun getById(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    val id: String = request.pathVariable("id")

    return mediaRepository.getById(id)
        .flatMap { resource ->
            ServerResponse.ok()
                .header(CONTENT_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(resource.downloadStream))
        }
        .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build())
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: I don't receive any exception, the request remains pending

Comment: Can you provide an example project so we can debug and track the issue down?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I share the link to the github repository: https://github.com/enricosecondulfo/ReactiveGridFsIssue

Comment: @mp911de I'm sorry if I'm pressing, but is there any news? Thank you very much

Comment: This looks like a bug. I filed https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2230.